# Find id by Name Jquery arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array of students (all IDs are unique):

```
[Object {ID: 1, "John"}, Object  {ID: 2, "Joseph"} ]
```

I have another array of strings `["John","Ram"]` (let's call this "Array 2").
How can I find the IDs of students whose names are there in Array 2 (without considering case, i.e. case insensitive)?

Comment: Should the 'other array of strings' be `["John","ram"]`?

Comment: `{ID: 1, "John"}` is not a proper object -- those name should be set in a property.

Comment: I edited as  Object {ID: 1, "John"}

Comment: ... that isn't valid JavaScript still. jQuery is just a JavaScript library - there is absolutely no need for the library in this instance. Anyway, surely the commas after each of the IDs are a mistake (that's a `SyntaxError`)?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Remove jQuery and fix case-sensitivity problem. Note, this is [no longer compatible with IE8](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) due to the use of `map()`, `forEach()` and `indexOf()` on `Array.prototype`.

Something along these lines would do the trick:

```
var names = ['John', 'Joe', 'Ralph'],
    data = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'John'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Joseph'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'ralph'
        }
    ],
    results = [];

var lnames = names.map(function(name) {
    return name.toLowerCase();
});

data.forEach(function(item) {
    if (lnames.indexOf(item.name.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        results.push(item.id);
    }
});

console.log('found: ', results);
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ptz3/2/

Comment: Here is a native JS solution btw - which _still_ doesn't answer OP's question because the question isn't well formed and the structure isn't clear: `var ids = studentsArray.filter(function(elem){
                  return namesArray.indexOf(elem.name) !== -1; /* in the names array*/
              }).map(function(elem){
                  return elem.ID;
              });`

Comment: Prior to the edit the last sentence in the question read: "[I am using jquery]"... So, to answer your question: the OP.

Comment: Apologies then, my bad. I did not see OP mentioned he was using jQuery before the edit.

Comment: No problem, thanks for pointing out jQuery was removed from the question. Also, I had to fix a case-sensitivity problem which I think may also be present in the solution you mention in your comment.